# Strange error with su - user

Tags: user-accounts, centos-6, su

On a CentOS server, I can log in via ssh correctly, however; if I su - oracle I get su: incorrect password.

I've changed the password and it continually says it's been updated.

If I sudo su - and then su - oracle it automatically logs in. 
Also, I'm not sure if connected, but when as oracle user, if I attempt to bring up anything x related or try and start an installer for Enterprise Manager, it says X11 Authentication error.

I'm thinking, there's something connected with how the logins work and something isn't being passed correctly with regards to accounts?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to the AMI I was using that had strange PAM settings enabled as well as some security set on pretty much all files that prevented a user that was created from doing anything.